# grid-template-column not showing up

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my grid column working? I'm making this Christmas matching game project and I am trying to make the other card columns using grid template columns but the other 3 columns aren't showing up. They should show up right next to "Time: 100" but aren't. I've checked my spelling and everything yet nothing is working. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Santa's Matching Game</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="page-title">Santa's Matching Game</h1>
    <!-- Game Stuff Besides Cards -->
    <div class="game-container">
        <div class="game-info-container">
            <div class="game-info">
                Time: <span id="time-remaining">100</span>
            </div>
            <div class="game-info">
                Flips: <span id="flips">0</span>
            </div>
    <!-- Cards -->
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>  

</html>
```

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Dancing-Bold";
    src: url("Assets/Fonts/Dancing-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');

}


@font-face {
    font-family: "MofC-Bold";
    src: url("Assets/Fonts/MofC-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');

}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


html {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(#f2f3f8,#58b69b);
}

.page-title {
    color:aliceblue;
    font-family: MofC-Bold, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6em;
}

.game-info {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: Dancing-Bold, serif;
}

.game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #d33943;
    height: 175px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Hopefully I did this right, I've never used Stack overflow before.

Answer (score 1):

Grid works with child elements, currently your gird only has one child wich is game-info-container, remove that element and the grid will work

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Dancing-Bold";
  src: url("Assets/Fonts/Dancing-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');

}


@font-face {
  font-family: "MofC-Bold";
  src: url("Assets/Fonts/MofC-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');

}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(#f2f3f8, #58b69b);
}

.page-title {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: MofC-Bold, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6em;
}

.game-info {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: Dancing-Bold, serif;
}

.game-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #d33943;
  height: 175px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title">Santa's Matching Game</h1>
<!-- Game Stuff Besides Cards -->
<div class="game-container">
  <div class="game-info">
    Time: <span id="time-remaining">100</span>
  </div>
  <div class="game-info">
    Flips: <span id="flips">0</span>
  </div>
  <!-- Cards -->
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I remove game-info-container im afraid that it will mess up what im trying to do. Is there something else i can do that will let me make the rest of my columns? like an alternative?